# How to make link download temporary in php

Tags: php

I see `mediafire.com` has link download will change after a time. And how to make it

Ex: now link download
`http://download886.mediafire.com/xvyys416wwrg/demo.zip`
after a time `xvyys416wwrg` will be change to a random string and old link `http://download886.mediafire.com/xvyys416wwrg/demo.zip` will not working

Answer (score 0):

You can reload a page after a certain time and give it a different URL or use JavaScript for this.

PHP solution:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["some_url"]))
{
echo '<a href="/'.$_SESSION["some_url"].'/demo.zip" />Link</a>';
}
else
{
echo '<a href="/starter_url/demo.zip" />Link</a>';
}
//Here is where you give it the new url
$_SESSION["some_url"]="whateverurl123";

header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );
```

Now the page will reload every 5 sec with whateverurl123 attached to the link. You can change that every time the page reloads.

You can achieve this without reloading the page using AJAX

Here is a little help

```
setInterval(function()
{ 
    $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url:"myurl.php",
      async: false}).success:function(data){
          $('#url_div').html('<a href="/'+data["generated_url"]+'/demo.zip" />Link</a>');
      }
    });
}, 5000);//time in milliseconds
```